# Повторить вращение объекта по физике

Tags: unity3d

На сцене есть два куба (2Д), куб1 физический, а куб2 нет. куб1 должен вращаться по физике, повторяя вращение куба2. Например если у куба2 вращение 45 градусов, то и куб1 должен повернутся на 45 градусов, но плавно и по физике. Пожалуйста напишите как можно это реализовать кодом, и чтобы была возможность в инспекторе менять скорость вращения куба1.

Вот что я пробовал (`rig` это Rigidbody2D куба1, а `obj` это куб2). 1 способ:

```
rig.angularVelocity += (obj.transform.eulerAngles.z - transform.eulerAngles.z) * stabSpeed;
```

2 способ:

```
if (transform.eulerAngles.z < obj.transform.eulerAngles.z) {
    rig.angularVelocity += stabSpeed;
} else if (transform.eulerAngles.z > obj.transform.eulerAngles.z) {
    rig.angularVelocity -= stabSpeed;
}
```

Но оно не работает (можете даже не проверять, оно по логике и не должно работать, так нельзя сравнивать углы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float selfAngle = transform.eulerAngles.z;
float targetAngle = obj.transform.eulerAngles.z;
float deltaAngle = Mathf.DeltaAngle(selfAngle, targetAngle);
```

`deltaAngle` это разница между поворотами двух объектов, то есть насколько первому нужно повернуться. Если скорость постоянная, от дельты нужен просто знак `speed*Mathf.Sign(deltaAngle)`. Вот с этой переменной и работай. На тему инспектора, это просто поле-множитель к скорости.

Comment: "По физике" это как? Физика не для плавности вращения нужна, а для **автоматического** физического взаимодействия твёрдых тел. Для плавного вращения используй Quaternion.RotateTowards или Quaternion.Lerp например.

Comment: @Qwer, постом ошибся, это ответ, а не вопрос.